# how to change data types, without change variable name JAVA

Tags: java, casting

I have 3 class `level1`, `level2`, and `player`. In `player` I have script like this

```
    private level1 play;
```

(`level1` is the name of class, and `play` is variable). I want to ask, how to change/cast `level1` to `level2` in `player` class without change the variable name.
Can I do that?

Comment: Your class design is bad. You need a single `Level` class, whose attributes should define each different level.

Comment: In addition to the replies given to help you solve your problem, you should also read and learn the java coding conventions here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html - class names shoud start with an uppercase letter,and variables should be nouns so `private Level1 currentLevel;` would be better.

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to create an interface. For example, the following will help:

```
public interface Level { }

public class Level1 implements Level { }

public class Level2 implements Level { }
```

This way, you can do:

```
private Level play;

public void start() {
   play = new Level1();

   if(play.isFinished()) {
       play = new Level2();
   }
}
```

It's just some example code, but I hope you catch my drift.

Comment: Most likely there will be enough shared code that `Level` should be a (probably abstract) superclass.

Comment: I recommend to use a more generic interface name like: `GameElement` since 'dtnder' needs to use this variable for players too.

Comment: @Kevin: could be, but there's not enough information in the original question to say how many shared code there is. A GameElement is nice, but not to start with.